# Veracode CWE ID 311: Cryptographic Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, veracode

**Veracode Cryptographic Issue**: CWE ID:311

**Description**: The application exposes potentially sensitive data by passing it into a function unencrypted. This could allow private data such as cryptographic keys or other sensitive information to be erroneously exposed.

**Recommendations**: Ensure that the application protects all sensitive data from unnecessary exposure.

**Error pointed on:**
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:@{NSFileModificationDate: [NSDate date]} ofItemAtPath:path error:nil];

Any suggestions, how to fix this issue ?

```
- (NSData*)loadContentsFromSecureFile:(NSString*)name ofType:(HCFileType)type
{
    NSString *path = [self pathForFile:name ofType:type];
    
    NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    if (encryptedData == nil) {
        DebugLog(@"No secure data found: %@", path);
        return nil;
    }
    
    NSData *data = [encryptedData AES256DecryptWithKey:[self.profile getFileKeyBytes]];
    if (data == nil) {
        DebugLog(@"Unable to decrypt data, deleting: %@", path);
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:nil];
        return nil;
    }
    
    // Error pointed on this below line.
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:@{NSFileModificationDate: [NSDate date]} ofItemAtPath:path error:nil];
    
    return data;
}
```

Comment: What issue do you believe you have here? Is this a question better sent to Veracode's technical support? Nothing in the specific line you've indicated suggests a problem; do you think there is one? Do you have any reason to believe this tool knows what it's talking about? (I strongly suspect that your AES256DecryptWithKey is completely broken, because most methods named like that are, but there's not enough code here to judge it, and "is this ad hoc encryption routine secure?" isn't well suited to Stack Overflow.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding attributes with permission as username, that will restrict anyone to read write file.

// Error pointed on this line

```
NSDictionary *attrib = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID,
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], NSFileOwnerAccountID,
                             @"username", NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName,
                             @"username", NSFileOwnerAccountName, NSFileModificationDate, [NSDate date]];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:attrib ofItemAtPath:path error:nil];
```